# how to direct default page to an spring controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml, url-pattern

The project(named:'myproject') use Spring MVC framework. The default page will be "index.action", web.xml configed as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-*.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.action</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The server response 404 not found When while visiting http://www.example.com/myproject/,  but it works fine while visiting http://www.example.com/myproject/index.action.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Changing the servlet mapping to the above means all request mappings will handled by spring.

Comment: But I just wanna handing .action requests by spring.Thanks anyway!

Comment: @RonHu so why are you calling www.xxx.com/myproject/ - thats not an action request